# Flutter: annot find plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, widget

I am trying to test a widget in my app, I am using GetIt locator:

```
void main() {
      setUpAll(() async {
        // WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
        await Firebase.initializeApp();
    
        configureDependencies();
      });
    
      testWidgets('check product print file widget exist',
          (WidgetTester tester) async {
        await tester.pumpWidget(
          MaterialApp(
            home: ScreenUtilInit(
                designSize: Size(360, 690),
                allowFontScaling: false,
                child: SplashPage()),
          ),
        );
        await tester.pumpAndSettle(const Duration(seconds: 5));
    
      });
    
     
    }
```

but when I run the test I get that error:

```
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core)
```

The SpalshScreenPage, don't implement any firebase package, it is just a simple page

Comment: You say you don't implement any firebase package but u are running 'Firebase.initializeApp()' in your Code...? Make sure to add the dependencies to your pubspec.yaml file

Comment: @Nuqo yes i installed all the dependencies, it works when I run the app, but not working when running tests